# Computational Complexity of Fourth Order Butterworth Filter and fastICA in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, filter, filtering, time-complexity

I am working on an EEG signal and I need to extract signal bands based on frequency.

Delta: 0 - 4Hz

Theta: 4 - 8Hz

Alpha: 8 - 12Hz

Beta : 12 - 40Hz

I used fourth order Butterworth filter and it works fine but I don't know the complexity of it, some people used the FastICA as well, so I need to know if it will be faster if I used fastICA. Could anyone tell me the complexity of both algorithms (fourth order Butterworth filter vs fastICA)?

Code to extract Theta band:

```
W1 = 8/fs;
W2 = 14/fs;
Wn_t = [W1 W2];
[c,d] = butter(N,Wn_t);
theta = filter(c,d,eeg);
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried. I don't know the answer, but it'll help others trying to answer.

Comment: also are methods you're testing built in Matlab functions?